# convert the following json to csv

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

There's 3 GB of JSON data that I want to convert into CSV format using Python. The piece of code I have written converts the data to CSV but stores it in a single cell. I don't want the "related" field (removed using re).

JSON Format

```
{'asin': '0001048791', 'salesRank': {'Books': 6334800}, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MKP0T4DBL.jpg', 'categories': [['Books']], 'title': 'The Crucible: Performed by Stuart Pankin, Jerome Dempsey &amp; Cast'}
{'asin': '0000143561', 'categories': [['Movies & TV', 'Movies']], 'description': '3Pack DVD set - Italian Classics, Parties and Holidays.', 'title': 'Everyday Italian (with Giada de Laurentiis), Volume 1 (3 Pack): Italian Classics, Parties, Holidays', 'price': 12.99, 'salesRank': {'Movies & TV': 376041}, 'imUrl': 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-site/icons/no-img-sm._CB192198896_.gif', 'related': {'also_viewed': ['B0036FO6SI', 'B000KL8ODE', '000014357X', 'B0037718RC', 'B002I5GNVU', 'B000RBU4BM'], 'buy_after_viewing': ['B0036FO6SI', 'B000KL8ODE', '000014357X', 'B0037718RC']}}
{'asin': '0000037214', 'related': {'also_viewed': ['B00JO8II76', 'B00DGN4R1Q', 'B00E1YRI4C']}, 'title': 'Purple Sequin Tiny Dancer Tutu Ballet Dance Fairy Princess Costume Accessory', 'price': 6.99, 'salesRank': {'Clothing': 1233557}, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31mCncNuAZL.jpg', 'brand': 'Big Dreams', 'categories': [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Girls'], ['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Novelty, Costumes & More', 'Costumes & Accessories', 'More Accessories', 'Kids & Baby']]}
{ "asin": "0000031852", "title": "Girls Ballet Tutu Zebra Hot Pink", "price": 3.17, "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51fAmVkTbyL._SY300_.jpg", "related": { "also_bought": ["B00JHONN1S", "B002BZX8Z6", "B00D2K1M3O", "0000031909", "B00613WDTQ", "B00D0WDS9A", "B00D0GCI8S", "0000031895", "B003AVKOP2", "B003AVEU6G", "B003IEDM9Q", "B002R0FA24", "B00D23MC6W", "B00D2K0PA0", "B00538F5OK", "B00CEV86I6", "B002R0FABA", "B00D10CLVW", "B003AVNY6I", "B002GZGI4E", "B001T9NUFS", "B002R0F7FE", "B00E1YRI4C", "B008UBQZKU", "B00D103F8U", "B007R2RM8W"], "also_viewed": ["B002BZX8Z6", "B00JHONN1S", "B008F0SU0Y", "B00D23MC6W", "B00AFDOPDA", "B00E1YRI4C", "B002GZGI4E", "B003AVKOP2", "B00D9C1WBM", "B00CEV8366", "B00CEUX0D8", "B0079ME3KU", "B00CEUWY8K", "B004FOEEHC", "0000031895", "B00BC4GY9Y", "B003XRKA7A", "B00K18LKX2", "B00EM7KAG6", "B00AMQ17JA", "B00D9C32NI", "B002C3Y6WG", "B00JLL4L5Y", "B003AVNY6I", "B008UBQZKU", "B00D0WDS9A", "B00613WDTQ", "B00538F5OK", "B005C4Y4F6", "B004LHZ1NY", "B00CPHX76U", "B00CEUWUZC", "B00IJVASUE", "B00GOR07RE", "B00J2GTM0W", "B00JHNSNSM", "B003IEDM9Q", "B00CYBU84G", "B008VV8NSQ", "B00CYBULSO", "B00I2UHSZA", "B005F50FXC", "B007LCQI3S", "B00DP68AVW", "B009RXWNSI", "B003AVEU6G", "B00HSOJB9M", "B00EHAGZNA", "B0046W9T8C", "B00E79VW6Q", "B00D10CLVW", "B00B0AVO54", "B00E95LC8Q", "B00GOR92SO", "B007ZN5Y56", "B00AL2569W", "B00B608000", "B008F0SMUC", "B00BFXLZ8M"], "bought_together": ["B002BZX8Z6"] }, "salesRank": {"Toys & Games": 211836}, "brand": "Coxlures", "categories": [["Sports & Outdoors", "Other Sports", "Dance"]] } 

import json
import re 
with open('metadata.json') as f:
    x = f.read()
    data = re.sub("\'related\': {","",x)
    data = re.sub("]},", "]", data)
    data = re.sub("}\n{", "},\n{", data)
    print("1")
    print(type(data))
    data = json.dumps(data)
    print("2")
    print(type(data))
    data = json.loads("[" + data + "]")
    print("3")
    print(type(data))
    print("done")


import pandas 
pandas.read_json(data.to_csv('metadata.csv')
```

I expect a proper CSV file having fields `[asin, title, categories, price, also_viewed, also_bought, brand]`

Comment: Add the code in the question please, and not in the comment!

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking... What do you mean with "stores it in a single cell"? What are you trying to achieve? Can you provide the contents of a small (!) JSON file, your actual (partially) working code, your expected output and the actual output? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you're not sure how to do that.

Comment: 0 {'asin': '0001048791', 'salesRank': {'Books': 6334800}, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MKP0T4DBL.jpg', 'categories': [['Books']], 'title': 'The Crucible: Performed by Stuart Pankin, Jerome Dempsey &amp; Cast'}, {'asin': '0000143561', 'categories': [['Movies & TV', 'Movies']], 'description': '3Pack DVD set - Italian Classics, Parties and Holidays.',

the data in csv format comes to a single cell, no columns and rows are created

Comment: {'asin': '0132793040', 'imUrl': 'http/images/IL.jpg', 'description': 'The   need.', 'categories': [['Electronics', 'Computer', 'Cables & Accessories', 'Monitor Accessories']], 'title': 'Kelby Training DVD: Mastering Blend Modes in Adobe Photoshop CS5 By Corey Barker'}
{'asin': '0321732944', 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31uogm6YcrL.jpg', 'categories': [['Electronics', 'Computers & Accessories', 'Cables & Accessories', 'Monitor Accessories']], 'title': 'Kelby Training DVD: Adobe Photoshop CS5  By Matt Kloskowski'}

I need the csv format of the data having above fields

Comment: @MandeepSahoo, as you've been told before: please don't put code in comments. It's highly unreadable. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56268923/edit) your question to add or update something.

Comment: CSV files don't have "cells". They just contain **C**omma-**S**eparated **V**alues. Maybe you're opening the CSV file with Excel, and it shows the data in one cell? But that could be another problem, not related to your code. So it helps if you clarify what you mean. If you're trying to use `pandas`, the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) might be very helpful (see the example at the bottom of that page).

Comment: Please show at least 1st 2-3 json objects in Q(Que/Problem). Not in comments. It seems your file is not a valid JSON file. As all objects/dicts are not in an array/list (I can it from what you pasted above). Can you add it in the Q if you pasted wrong JSON,  may be you forgot to add brackets at very first or last in that. In place of `{... }{... }`,  it should be either `[{...}{...}]` or `{0: {... },  1: {... }}` or in any other valid JSON form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if I understand you correctly, you have a JSON file containing an array of objects that contain the mentioned fields. You want to store a number of these fields into a CSV file. The JSON data contains a field "related", which has sub fields "also_viewed" and "also_bought". You want the two latter sub fields as separate columns in the CSV file, and do not want to have a column "related" in the CSV file. Right? If I misunderstood you, please try to clarify your question.

Python can handle JSON and CSV data using the standard library modules ([json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)). However, you will have to write the "glue logic" yourself. I do not recommend to perform regular expressions on the JSON data, because it's very error-prone. Furthermore, your current code performs multiple operations on the data and has multiple copies of the data in memory, so it will probably be slow and you'll quickly run out of memory.

Below is a working example based on standard Python modules. However, I don't know the format of your input data (the JSON data in your question is not valid JSON format!) and I don't know exactly in which format you want to output lists. I have made some assumptions, but you may want to change the code if you expect a different output format. But the code *does* output valid CSV data, which can be opened in a spreadsheet application (e.g. LibreOffice Calc).

Note that this version also loads the JSON file at once. It's much more memory efficient than you current implementation, but still consumes a lot of memory if the JSON file is 3 GB. If you have enough memory, this does not have to be a problem (as long as you're using the 64-bit version of Python). However, you could also implement a parser based on a streaming JSON parser (I've got it working using [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/), but it's a bit more code and I'm not sure if I should post it as an answer). That will greatly reduce the memory consumption. The CSV file is already written line by line, so that does not require much memory.

So, now the code :-)

I assume your JSON data is like this:

```
[
{"asin": "0001048791", "salesRank": {"Books": 6334800}, "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MKP0T4DBL.jpg", "categories": [["Books"]], "title": "The Crucible: Performed by Stuart Pankin, Jerome Dempsey &amp; Cast"},
{"asin": "0000143561", "categories": [["Movies & TV", "Movies"]], "description": "3Pack DVD set - Italian Classics, Parties and Holidays.", "title": "Everyday Italian (with Giada de Laurentiis), Volume 1 (3 Pack): Italian Classics, Parties, Holidays", "price": 12.99, "salesRank": {"Movies & TV": 376041}, "imUrl": "http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-site/icons/no-img-sm._CB192198896_.gif", "related": {"also_viewed": ["B0036FO6SI", "B000KL8ODE", "000014357X", "B0037718RC", "B002I5GNVU", "B000RBU4BM"], "buy_after_viewing": ["B0036FO6SI", "B000KL8ODE", "000014357X", "B0037718RC"]}},
{"asin": "0000037214", "related": {"also_viewed": ["B00JO8II76", "B00DGN4R1Q", "B00E1YRI4C"]}, "title": "Purple Sequin Tiny Dancer Tutu Ballet Dance Fairy Princess Costume Accessory", "price": 6.99, "salesRank": {"Clothing": 1233557}, "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31mCncNuAZL.jpg", "brand": "Big Dreams", "categories": [["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Girls"], ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Novelty, Costumes & More", "Costumes & Accessories", "More Accessories", "Kids & Baby"]]},
{"asin": "0000031852", "title": "Girls Ballet Tutu Zebra Hot Pink", "price": 3.17, "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51fAmVkTbyL._SY300_.jpg", "related": { "also_bought": ["B00JHONN1S", "B002BZX8Z6", "B00D2K1M3O", "0000031909", "B00613WDTQ", "B00D0WDS9A", "B00D0GCI8S", "0000031895", "B003AVKOP2", "B003AVEU6G", "B003IEDM9Q", "B002R0FA24", "B00D23MC6W", "B00D2K0PA0", "B00538F5OK", "B00CEV86I6", "B002R0FABA", "B00D10CLVW", "B003AVNY6I", "B002GZGI4E", "B001T9NUFS", "B002R0F7FE", "B00E1YRI4C", "B008UBQZKU", "B00D103F8U", "B007R2RM8W"], "also_viewed": ["B002BZX8Z6", "B00JHONN1S", "B008F0SU0Y", "B00D23MC6W", "B00AFDOPDA", "B00E1YRI4C", "B002GZGI4E", "B003AVKOP2", "B00D9C1WBM", "B00CEV8366", "B00CEUX0D8", "B0079ME3KU", "B00CEUWY8K", "B004FOEEHC", "0000031895", "B00BC4GY9Y", "B003XRKA7A", "B00K18LKX2", "B00EM7KAG6", "B00AMQ17JA", "B00D9C32NI", "B002C3Y6WG", "B00JLL4L5Y", "B003AVNY6I", "B008UBQZKU", "B00D0WDS9A", "B00613WDTQ", "B00538F5OK", "B005C4Y4F6", "B004LHZ1NY", "B00CPHX76U", "B00CEUWUZC", "B00IJVASUE", "B00GOR07RE", "B00J2GTM0W", "B00JHNSNSM", "B003IEDM9Q", "B00CYBU84G", "B008VV8NSQ", "B00CYBULSO", "B00I2UHSZA", "B005F50FXC", "B007LCQI3S", "B00DP68AVW", "B009RXWNSI", "B003AVEU6G", "B00HSOJB9M", "B00EHAGZNA", "B0046W9T8C", "B00E79VW6Q", "B00D10CLVW", "B00B0AVO54", "B00E95LC8Q", "B00GOR92SO", "B007ZN5Y56", "B00AL2569W", "B00B608000", "B008F0SMUC", "B00BFXLZ8M"], "bought_together": ["B002BZX8Z6"] }, "salesRank": {"Toys & Games": 211836}, "brand": "Coxlures", "categories": [["Sports & Outdoors", "Other Sports", "Dance"]] }
]
```

Python solution:

```py
import csv
import json

CSV_COLUMNS = ['asin', 'title', 'categories', 'price',
               'also_bought', 'also_viewed', 'brand']


class DataConverter:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.writer = None

    def _get_categories(self, item):
        groups = item.get('categories', [[]])
        formatted_groups = []
        for group in groups:
            formatted_groups.append('(' + ', '.join(group) + ')')
        return ', '.join(formatted_groups)

    def _get_also_bought(self, item):
        related = item.get('related', {})
        also_bought = related.get('also_bought', [])
        return ', '.join(also_bought)

    def _get_also_viewed(self, item):
        related = item.get('related', {})
        also_viewed = related.get('also_viewed', [])
        return ', '.join(also_viewed)

    def _process(self, item):
        """Process one data item.

        Expects a Python representation of a JSON object.
        Returns a list of strings (one row of the CSV file).
        """
        asin = item.get('asin', '')
        title = item.get('title', '')
        categories = self._get_categories(item)
        price = item.get('price', '')
        also_bought = self._get_also_bought(item)
        also_viewed = self._get_also_viewed(item)
        brand = item.get('brand', '')
        return [asin, title, categories, price, also_bought, also_viewed,
                brand]

    def convert(self):
        """Convert the JSON file to a CSV file."""
        # Open the JSON file.
        with open(self.filename + '.json', 'rb') as json_file:
            # Parse the JSON data.
            data = json.load(json_file)
            # Open the CSV file.
            with open(self.filename + '.csv', 'wt', newline='') as csv_file:
                # Create the CSV writer object.
                self.writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                # Write the header row.
                self.writer.writerow(CSV_COLUMNS)
                # Write CSV rows, one by one.
                for item in data:
                    row = self._process(item)
                    self.writer.writerow(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DataConverter('metadata').convert()
```